# C# ?: Ternary Operator - Unexpected symbol '?' - Error

Tags: c#, recursion, conditional-statements

This is my attempt to solve a small problem about The Collatz Conjecture.
I get  **error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `?'**
I can't figure out what have I misunderstood about the ?: operator.

```
public class Program
{
    int Step = -1;
    
    public static int collatz(int num)
    {
        Step++;
        (num%2 == 0) ? collatz(num/2) :
            (num%2 == 1) ? : return Step : collatz(num*3+1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you are using turnery is wrong. What do you expect your end result to be ?

Comment: Remove `: return`

Comment: `(num%2 == 1) ? : return Step` there's nothing between `?` and the next `:`

Comment: @Camilo That's not the only problem. That line doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yeah, I know, there are too many problems really

Comment: @alt72 I'm not familiar with "The Collatz Conjecture" so I'm not really sure what you're trying to calculate. Perhaps, you can show us what you're trying to do with a traditional `if .. else` statement so we can help you with the ternary operator.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that ':' in front of the '?'. Somehow the whole expression still makes sense to me. Here is a link to the problem : https://edabit.com/challenge/F6m5ZRyzK5fmqTrBG

Comment: Something that uses a ternary operator is an *expression* and is used to compute a *value*. An example of a *statement* that uses a ternary operator is `var z = (x > y) ? x : y;` That's an *assignment statement*; the variable `z` is assigned the *value* that results from evaluating the ternary *expression*. Your ternary-ish line of code isn't a statement and includes unparsable fragments like `(num%2 == 1) ? : return Step : `. What are you trying to express?

Comment: According to Wikipedia's description of Collatz conjecture, it seems like all you need is `return (num % 2 == 0) ? collatz(num / 2) : collatz(num * 3 + 1);`. I'm not sure what the purpose of `Step` is. Are you trying to increment it or something?

Comment: @41686d6564 Well, that plus some condition that terminates the recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you have `? :` in the middle of this expression:

```
(num%2 == 1) ? :
```

With a ternary, it is supposed to be `<expr> ? <expr> : <expr>;`
You cannot have `?` and `:` without an expression in between.

---

Next, you cannot `return` from the middle of a ternary expression.

And then, you must do something with the result of the expression:  You must assign it, return it, pass it to a function, etc.   You cannot have a ternary that just "does nothing".

Based on your code, I think you want to return the value of the entire expression.

Fixing all these problems, you get:

```
public static int collatz(int num)
{
    Step++;
    return (num%2 == 0) ? collatz(num/2) :
           (num%2 == 1) ? Step : collatz(num*3+1); 
}
```

---

Finally, fixing up the problems in your algorithm, I got:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Collatz Value {0}; Num Steps {1}\n", 12, collatz(12)));
        return 0;
    }
    
    public static int collatz(int num)
    {
        return (num == 1)? 0 : 1 + collatz( (num%2==0)? num/2 : num*3+1 );
    }
}
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/m6qnre)

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0.02s 16104KB
Collatz Value 12; Num Steps 9
```

Comment: When would `collatz(num*3+1)` execute though? A number modulo 2 either returns 0 or 1 (for any positive integer)

Comment: Isn't the result of `intValue % 2` either 0 or 1 anyway? The `(num%2 == 1)` part seems redundant to me (and consequently, `? Step` also doesn't make sense).

Comment: @OlivierRogier No, 100%3 is not 3 unless someone has implemented modulo incorrectly. Mod n should never have more than n possible outcomes, at least for positive numbers (in my opinion also not otherwise, but not everyone agrees)

Comment: Yeah, it should be `num == 1` instead of `num%2 == 1`.

Comment: I can only fix so much of the poster's code.   I identified multiple problems, and addressed them all.    The code now compiles and runs.   Getting it to do the right algorithm is another problem, and the poster's responsibility, not mine.

Comment: @abelenky Thanks for clarifying and sorry for the extremely bad written code, I'm just starting to learn C#. It's quite confusing learning it just after learning Python. Again, thanks.